# Formal Logic Reading List

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

My focus for my undergraduate studies was computer science, but I have been becoming more and more interested in studying formal logic on my own, and am looking for book recommendations to develop a better mastery of the subject.

My limited experience includes an introductory class on Symbolic Logic, as well as some work with the [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) programming language.

So far in my research I have found the following resources:

- [First Order Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486683702)
- [Teach Yourself Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/)

Does anyone have any other essential texts for learning formal logic?